# in a wordpress webpage, how can I remove the "proudly powered by WordPress." logo

Tags: wordpress

I'm quite new to word press, and web development in general.

I am trying to remove the "powered by wordpress" and the wordpress logo from the bottom of my page, is there a way to do that?

I'm using twenty ten scheme.

Kind Regards

Comment: I googled "remove powered by wordpress" and found at least 8 tutorials... some with videos.

Comment: thanks for the tip... I found it. it's so funny how sometimes you forget to do the trivial. thanks!

Comment: If possible try to add the solution.In order to close this question.At the same time,some may get benefited from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Twenty Eleven, you can remove the code directly by going to: Appearance > Editor, then edit the Footer.php file and remove the line:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>" rel="generator"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
```

This will get overwritten the next time you update the theme. You can hide the whole credits block by editing you style.css and adding the line:

```
#site-generator { display: none; }
```

This will probably also get overwritten the next time you update your theme. [Here is a more detailed explanation of the above for the twentyten theme](http://www.blog.web6.org/remove-proudly-powered-by-wordpress/).